# Can you pass a variable in a Linux file path?

Tags: linux, file

I'm working with a proprietary software and I need to pass a small value from one process to another. If I were to do this with URLs I would do something like:

```
https://www.acme.com?some-piece-of-data
```

One process would send the url to another process and the second process would parse "some-piece-of-data" off.

However, I'm working with a Linux file system. Is there some kind of Linux Easter egg or way to pass a small value via the file path?

Something like:

```
/opt/acme/file.pdf?some-piece-of-data
```

I need the filepath to work in Linux but also retain the variable so I can extract it and use it while processing the file.

Comment: You could encode a small integer value, without actually changing the file the path refers to, by inserting that many instances of `./` - at the beginning for a relative path, after any directory name for an absolute path.  I can't think of any similar trick for arbitrary string values.

Comment: You could create a dir `/hack`  with a bunch of keywords symlinks to itself, and encode arbitrary tags with `/hack/foo/bar/baz/etc/../actual/path/to/file` but... eww

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to embed extra data in a *bona fide* filesystem path, in part because every character apart from `/` and the null character is allowed in file (and directory) names.

If you're willing to encode the path or limit what paths are allowed then you can devise a URL-like mechanism that specific software could recognize and decode, but that would not be usable directly with the shell or other general-purpose software.